# I store float values in hdf5 but caffe says Datatype class: H5T_INTEGER

Tags: python, caffe, hdf5

I am writing my files to a hdf5.file like this:

```
image = np.zeros( (split, 1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE), dtype=np.float )

img = img.astype(np.float)
image[counter] = img[np.newaxis, :, :]
....
H.create_dataset( 'data', data=image)
```

And I receive in caffe the output:

```
I0828 09:25:57.495980 21298 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:79] Loading list of HDF5 filenames from: train_h5_list.txt
I0828 09:25:57.509590 21298 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:93] Number of HDF5 files: 8259
I0828 09:25:57.566036 21296 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:79] Loading list of HDF5 filenames from: train_h5_list.txt
I0828 09:25:57.879372 21296 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:93] Number of HDF5 files: 8259
I0828 09:25:58.406316 21297 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:79] Loading list of HDF5 filenames from: train_h5_list.txt
I0828 09:25:58.418432 21297 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:93] Number of HDF5 files: 8259
I0828 09:26:02.211232 21262 solver.cpp:273] Solving train
I0828 09:26:02.211280 21262 solver.cpp:274] Learning Rate Policy: fixed
I0828 09:26:02.214079 21262 solver.cpp:331] Iteration 0, Testing net (#0)
I0828 09:26:18.361723 21262 hdf5.cpp:35] Datatype class: H5T_INTEGER
```

*EDIT*

When using `as.type('f4')` it looks like this:

```
h5ls train2102.h5

data                     Dataset {100, 1, 256, 256}
volume                   Dataset {100, 128, 128, 128}
```

With -v it looks like this:

```
data                     Dataset {100/100, 1/1, 256/256, 256/256}
Location:  1:800
Links:     1
Storage:   26214400 logical bytes, 26214400 allocated bytes, 100.00% utilization
Type:      native float
volume                   Dataset {100/100, 128/128, 128/128, 128/128}
Location:  1:1400
Links:     1
Storage:   838860800 logical bytes, 838860800 allocated bytes, 100.00% utilization
Type:      native float
```

It looks much better now!

Comment: can you show the output of `h5ls` on your hdf5 binary files?

Comment: What output do you mean? @Shai

Comment: run the command line tool [`h5ls`](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/cmdtoolview.html#h5ls) on your hdf5 binary file and see what it outputs.

Comment: Okay, done. @Shai

Comment: Is it correct now? @Shai

Comment: as you can see your HDF5 is in `double` (float64) format and not `single` (float32). You need to fix that.

Comment: What do you mean? How do I fix that?

Comment: By using converting: `img.astype(np.float)` to `img.astype('float32)` ? @Shai

Comment: I usually use `.astype('f4')` for 4byte (=32bit) floating point.

Comment: What is the difference between `float32` and `f4` ?@Shai

Comment: I don't think there's a difference.

Comment: Okay I am using `f4` as well now! @Shai Thank you!

Comment: @Shai Could you have  a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45959507/failed-to-read-float-dataset-in-caffe-using-hdf5) please? I really do not know what is going on there and you seem to know a lot!